# Efficient way to slice a 2D array and skip indices; extract small segments repeatedly

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have a 2D numpy array D, which has Dimensions (1000, 800). I want to extract small segments of length 20 from the array:

Assume D[0][:] is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...] and I want segments of length 3, I'd like the first three numbers (1, 2, 3), then skip some indices (say 60), extract 3, skip 60, and so on.

I know that I can do D[:,start:end:step], but is there something like D[:,start:end:step*:skip*]?

Ideally, I want something like:

```
D = np.random.random((1000,800))
parts = D[:,0:20:1:skip_n_indices_and_repeat]
```

I appreciate your time and answers. If you have got an easier or different solution please propose. Thank you.

Comment: I guess your example is too complicated because you can minimize it giving a minimal working example of 1D array

Comment: This is what `as_strided` is for: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html or alternatively you could try to reshape the array in such a way that the elements of interesst are placed in a specific axis. E.g assuming that you got a 1d array, you could reshape it to `(:, 10)` to get a striding of 10 and then extract the first three columns in order to get three elements every 10 elements.

Comment: If the skip is a multiple of 3, you can reshape `D` to `(1000, -1, 3)` (you'd have to slice out the last couple of columns first in this case) and with that you can use the slice `[:, ::20]` (or `[::21]` if you want to skip 60 values without counting the three picked ones) and then reshape back to `(1000, -1)` (in this case it would give shape `(1000, 15)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no use of any special methods, it's possible to generate a mask of indexes needed like this:

```
D = np.random.random((1000,800))
step = 3
skip = 60
idx = np.arange(800)
needed_indexes = idx%(skip+step)<step
```

Then you can return a copy of your array in a standard way:

```
>>> E = D[:,needed_indexes]
>>> E.shape
(1000, 39)
```